# Run option not highlighted in Netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: 13.04, eclipse, netbeans

I have installed Netbeans 7.3.1 in ubuntu 13.04 to run java programs but i am unable to run  any program since none of the options under the Run menu is highlighted even the shortcuts like Shift + F6 is not working. I tried the older version of the netbeans (available in the ubuntu software center) but facing the same problem. I re installed many times but all in vain. 
Similarly, when i tried running eclipse it says

Select what to run
1. Ant Build
2. Ant Build...

and then tried both the option but in both the option it says "Build failed. Unable to find an Ant file to run".

And it works fine when i run any java program from the terminal.

Whats the problem and how can i configure these IDEs. I have open jdk 7 (from ubuntu software center) installed in ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you installed NetBeans from the repositories. If you did, go to the Plugins Manager (that's on the tools windows I think), and check that you have installed at least the following plugins:

- Ant
- Java
- Java Debugger
- NetBeans branding
- NetBeans platform

I may be missing something but play around the plugins. When you install NetBeans from the repos, it does not installs much plugins with it, and Java support, as almost everything else in NetBeans, is a plugin.

Good luck!